# What is "torsion" in the context of cohomology, and why is it important?

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I searched for some answers, but most answers discussed the meaning of torsion, instead of its definition. Not knowing how the torsion is defined (in cohomology) I couldn't understand those answers at all.

Comment: A group has torsion if there exists an element with finite order, i.e. a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Sometimes de Rham cohomology is defined as a vector space, in which case torsion doesn't make sense, but cohomology can more generally be defined as an abelian group, and hence you get torsion as explained by @DanRust.